# WSL: how do I set the group for a tty device

Tags: usb, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, udev

I am running usbipd on windows 11 to enable USB devices to attach to WSL. This works. I can run my serial application as root and it works fine. I would rather not run my application as root. My user is in group dialout (and tty).

I cannot get the group of a FTDI serial port to change from root:

```
:~$ ls /dev/ttyUS* -Al
crw------- 1 root root 188, 0 May 13 08:07 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Notice that the group is root and the permissions are 188.
lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I set up a udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", GROUP:="dialout", MODE:="0666"
```

I have a feeling that my udev rules are incorrect, but I looked around and cannot figure out what might be wrong.
My method to test changes:

1. make change to udev rules
2. close ubuntu terminal, in windows type wsl --shutdown
3. Open Ubuntu terminal
4. in windows, type usbipd wsl attach --busid 10-3

   - (device attaches, windows makes a noise as it does)
5. ls /dev and check the user & permissions

```
~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 /dev/ttyUSB1
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

Comment: Great question -- I did try this myself a while back with similar udev rules, but I was also unsuccessful.  I started to ask a question on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) but I never finished writing it up.  I'll try to dust off what I tried and compare notes.

Comment: Note the results of your `ls /dev/ttyUS* -Al` command. It grants access only to the `root` user, not the `root` group. The device setup is the problem. For more information, `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/ttyUS`.

Comment: @waltinator - Added result of journal. What do you mean by "device setup" - where would the device be setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my recipe to enable permission modification of a USB device (RP2040 pico dev board via `/dev/ttyACM0` or Wemos D1 mini on `/dev/ttyUSB0`) attached via `usbipd` on WSL (working at least with Ubuntu/Debian distributions).

By default, Systemd seems to not be started at WSL startup.
By following [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1701853/how-to-enable-a-service-to-start-with-wsl2), I modified `/etc/wsl.conf` by adding:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Then stopped WSL (`wsl --shutdown`) and restarted.

After having attached a device via usbipd (`usbipd wsl attach --busid XXX`), the corresponding device (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) become accessible with `group="dialout"` and `+rw` permissions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I've been annoyed at udev not working for 2 weeks. Not starting systemd by default is a strange choice and introduces weird bugs like serial device permissions getting broken.

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm. Such a weird workaround...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the rules to update the permissions by creating the file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.devices.rules

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="usb_device_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb|tty|hidraw", GOTO="usb_device_rules_end"

#ESP32 WOOT Dev Board (Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge)
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev", TAG+="uaccess"

LABEL="usb_device_rules_end"
```

I then ran `sudo udevadm control --reload`

It could have been the missing product id?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).